# A particular cases of second Hardy-Littlewood conjecture

Tags: analytic-number-theory

Can someone solve this problem?

(or does someone known a proof of this problem, if it exists?)

for every $n\geq 2$, $\pi(2n)\leq 2\pi(n)$.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: could you elaborate on what exactly you mean by "*solve*"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By the prime number theorem,
\[2\pi(x) - \pi(2x) = 2 \int_{2}^{x} \frac{dt}{\log t} - \int_{2}^{2x} \frac{dt}{\log t} + O\left(x\exp(-c\sqrt{\log x})\right).\]
By making the change of variables $t \mapsto t/2$ in the second integral, the two integrals become
\[2 \int_{2}^{x} \frac{dt}{\log t} - 2 \int_{1}^{x} \frac{dt}{\log 2t},\]
which is
\[2 \log 2 \int_{2}^{x} \frac{dt}{\log t(\log t + \log 2)} - 2 \int_{1}^{2} \frac{dt}{\log t + \log 2}.
\]
Using integration by parts, one can show that this is asymptotic to $2 \log 2 \frac{x}{(\log x)^2}$, and so
\[2\pi(x) - \pi(2x) \sim 2 \log 2 \frac{x}{(\log x)^2}.\]
So it is certainly true that $2\pi(x) \geq \pi(2x)$ for all sufficiently large $x$.

Comment: Thank you!!  The proof that i've found of this problem works in the same way with the form of prime number theorem that follows by the Riemann hypothesis ($\pi(x)=Li(x)+O(\sqrt{x}log(x)) $). I don't know the theorem of  De La Vallée Poussin. Thank's very much!