# Number of primes in $]x,2x]$ compared to in $[0,x]$ for $x > 0$

Tags: prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory

Show there exists a $K > 0$ such that for all $x> K$ the interval $]x,2x]$ contains fewer primes than the interval $[0,x]$.

My approach so far has been to try to show $\pi(2x)-2\pi(x)$ is negative for all $x>K$ as this would be the desired conclusion. My idea is to apply the Prime Number Theorem, but so far I have not been able to do it in a fruitful way.

I would appreciate any help or hints for this problem. Thanks!

Comment: Not that it helps, but the lowest such $K$ is $10$

Comment: @Henry You can become a little more helpful if you provide a reference for that :)

Comment: I think that you need to use the lowest and highest bounds of the prime-counting function, i.e., prove that $H_{\pi(2x)}-2L_{\pi(x)}$ is negative.

Comment: @Wojowu: the original question is obviously true with the difference tending to widen as $x$ increases, with "obvious" meaning "I will leave it to others to prove". My statement comes from looking at the differences for $x$ up to $50000$, by which time it is well over $600$

Comment: See this answer for a more precise asymptotic: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1426666/a-particular-cases-of-second-hardy-littlewood-conjecture/1427143#1427143

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the prime number theorem in the form
$$\pi(y) = \int_2^y \frac{1}{\log t}dt + O_A(y (\log y)^{-A}).$$
We have
$$2\pi(x) - \pi(2x) = \int_2^x \frac{1}{\log t}dt - \int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{\log t}dt + O_A(x (\log x)^{-A}),$$
and we easily see that
$$\int_x^{2x}\frac{1}{\log t}dt \leq \frac{x}{\log x}.$$
If we now integrate by parts once, we get
$$\int_2^x \frac{1}{\log t}dt = O(1) + \frac{x}{\log x} + \int_2^x \frac{1}{\log^2 t}dt,$$
so
$$2\pi(x) - \pi(2x) \geq (1+o(1))\int_2^x \frac{1}{\log^2 t}dt \gg \frac{x}{\log^2 x}$$
as $x$ tends to infinity.

Comment: Again not helping much, but in fact $2\pi(x) - \pi(2x) \geq  \dfrac{x}{(\log_e x)^2}$ for $x \ge 101$